# Is it possible to use Google Fusion Tables with a custom overlay?

Tags: overlay, google-fusion-tables

here is what I would like to achieve:

I need to use an custom overlay like this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple

as background for a set of points loaded from a Google Fusion Table like this

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-fusiontables-simple

Also if you could confirm this: I read that you can configure a custom icon for each point you display by adding a link to an icon in your Fusion table. Has anybody tired this?

I have searched examples for the above but I could not find an all in one example

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not display custom icons on FusionTablesLayer ([it only displays a defined set of markers](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1BDnT5U1Spyaes0Nj3DXciJKa_tuu7CzNRXWdVA#map%3aid=3)), you can use the data in the FusionTable to create native Google Maps API v3 custom icons, but you lose the performance benefit of FusionTablesLayer tiled rendering (which will be an issue if you have lots of markers).

[example from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/custom_markers)

[combination of the 2 Google examples](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-fusiontables-simple_wOverlay.html)

Comment: I only have around 80 points to render. I am able to create each of the above types of maps individually but I do not know how to put the fusion table layer on top of the custom overlay map created as indicated in the first example. I am not too worried about performance in this case. So from what you are saying I will have to use markers and to define  custom icons for each class of markers, is that right ?

Comment: See my updated answer if all you are trying to do is combine those 2 examples.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. The only thing that is missing is to colour the circles with different colours but that, from what I read,  is not possible with Google Fusion Tables. Thanks a lot!

Comment: On my side I managed to use markers to put my points on the map but your solution is more elegant and more flexible